# Deleting Release Objects via the API

Tags: rally

When I try to delete release objects via that API, I get back:

```
Cannot delete objects of type Release
```

I guess Rally is trying to prevent major wrangling of a project via the API?  I presume this is an intentional decision, but it seems kind of like an ad-hoc.  I mean, I can screw up a release pretty well by deleting stories, defects PI's too...

What is the thinking behind this restriction?  Is it perhaps time to revisit it?  Is there any easy way around it?

The reason I'm playing around in this area is because I'm moving over to having portfolio items hooked into releases and making tools for the switch over from our current system of tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is not possible to delete releases via WS API. This is an intentional decision. Unfortunately at this point there is no workaround, and no immediate plans to change the API to allow deletion of those objects.

Comment: Actually iterations can be deleted as of about this time last year.  Not sure why releases weren't given the same treatment at the same time.  Probably at least worth a vote on Rally Ideas...

Comment: I'm guessing that this policy was put into place before you could "undelete" release objects from the recycling bin like you can now...